# How am I able to figure out why apache/php crashes?

Tags: logging, log-files, windows-event-log

I have a problem which is driving me and a few clients on this server totally nuts.

The problem is that PHP (or I guess Apache) seems to be crashing randomly and almost on a daily basis.

The dedicated server I have is running Linux and Plesk 9.5 and has 1gb of ram and is only really running 5 websites which don't get a significant amount of traffic.

I have gone through the httpd error_log as the web host suggested and I did find a bunch of issues being reported by php for each of the 5 wordpress 3.0 sites. Mainly related to missing php include files and things like that all which I ended up resolving.

Unfortunately, none of the issue I fixed seem to have been related to apache crashing so my question to you guys here is what do I do next.

Naturally I would like to know exactly why this is happening so I can not only resolve this problem right now but also know how to correctly diagnose a problem like this in the future.

My web hosts solution was to just add more ram but although this "may" be the actual reason I can't believe these 5 sites are sucking so much ram.

In any case I am just looking for the exact steps you experts would use to diagnose and resolve this.

Additionally - Below I have included a few bullet points for other unresolved errors listed within my errors_log file as I don't know if any of this is helpful.

> [Mon Dec 13 17:00:53 2010] [warn]
>   Init: You should not use name-based
>   virtual hosts in conjunction with
>   SSL!! [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54 2010]
>   [notice] ModSecurity for Apache 2.1.7
>   configured - Apache/2.2.8 (Fedora)
>   [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54 2010] [warn]
>   module jk_module is already loaded,
>   skipping [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54 2010]
>   [warn] module ssl_module is already
>   loaded, skipping [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54
>   2010] [notice] Digest: generating
>   secret for digest authentication ...
>   [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54 2010] [notice]
>   Digest: done [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54
>   2010] [warn] RSA server certificate
>   CommonName (CN) `plesk' does NOT match
>   server name!? [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54
>   2010] [warn] RSA server certificate
>   CommonName (CN)`
>   domain****.com' does NOT
>   match server name!? [Mon Dec 13
>   17:00:54 2010] [warn] RSA server
>   certificate CommonName (CN)
>   `domain****.com' does NOT
>   match server name!? [Mon Dec 13
>   17:00:54 2010] [warn] RSA server
>   certificate CommonName (CN)`
>   domain****.com' does NOT
>   match server name!? [Mon Dec 13
>   17:00:54 2010] [warn] Init: SSL server
>   IP/port conflict: atmail.webmail:443
>   (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_atmail_vhost.conf:48)
>   vs. horde.webmail:443
>   (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_horde_vhost.conf:41)
>   [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54 2010] [warn]
>   Init: SSL server IP/port conflict:
>   wp3.excitesteps.com:443
>   (/var/www/vhosts/domain****.com/conf/httpd.include:13)
>   vs. horde.webmail:443
>   (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_horde_vhost.conf:41)
>   [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54 2010] [warn]
>   Init: SSL server IP/port conflict:
>   domain******.com:443
>   (/var/www/vhosts/domain******.com/conf/httpd.include:13)
>   vs. horde.webmail:443
>   (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_horde_vhost.conf:41)
>   [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54 2010] [warn]
>   Init: SSL server IP/port conflict:
>   domain******.com:443
>   (/var/www/vhosts/domain******.com/conf/httpd.include:13)
>   vs. horde.webmail:443
>   (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_horde_vhost.conf:41)
>   [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54 2010] [warn]
>   Init: SSL server IP/port conflict:
>   default-2**-1**-2**-2**:443
>   (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zz010_psa_httpd.conf:84)
>   vs. horde.webmail:443
>   (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_horde_vhost.conf:41)
>   [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54 2010] [warn]
>   Init: You should not use name-based
>   virtual hosts in conjunction with
>   SSL!! [Mon Dec 13 17:00:54 2010]
>   [notice] mod_bw : Memory Allocated 0
>   bytes (each conf takes 32 bytes) [Mon
>   Dec 13 17:00:54 2010] [notice] mod_bw
>   : Version 0.8 - Initialized [0 Confs]
>   [Mon Dec 13 17:00:55 2010] [notice]
>   mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes
>   based on 256 max processes and 0 max
>   threads. [Mon Dec 13 17:00:55 2010]
>   [notice] mod_python: using
>   mutex_directory /tmp  [Mon Dec 13
>   17:00:55 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.8
>   (Unix) DAV/2 mod_jk/1.2.15
>   mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8b
>   mod_auth_kerb/5.3 mod_auth_pgsql/2.0.3
>   Apache/2.2.0 (Fedora) PHP/5.2.6
>   mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5
>   mod_perl/2.0.3 Perl/v5.8.8 configured
>   -- resuming normal operations [Mon Dec 13 18:09:26 2010] [error] [client
>   6**.5**.3**.1**] File does not exist: /usr/share/psa-horde/robots.txt [Mon
>   Dec 13 18:09:27 2010] [error] [client
>   6**.5**.3**.1**] ModSecurity: Could not set variable
>   "resource.alerted_960903_compression"
>   as the collection does not exist.
>   [hostname "webmail.domain****.com"]
>   [uri "/index.php"] [unique_id
>   "T2ObHH8AAAEAACAU36UAAAAA"] [Mon Dec
>   13 18:09:27 2010] [error] [client
>   6**.5**.**.1**] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator EQ match: 0. [id "960903"]
>   [msg "ModSecurity does not support
>   content encodings"] [severity
>   "WARNING"] [hostname
>   "webmail.domain****.com"] [uri
>   "/index.php"] [unique_id
>   "T2ObHH8AAAEAACAU36UAAAAA"] [Mon Dec
>   13 18:09:28 2010] [error] [client
>   6**.5**.3**.1**] ModSecurity: Could not set variable
>   "resource.alerted_960903_compression"
>   as the collection does not exist.
>   [hostname "webmail.domain******.com"]
>   [uri "/login.php"] [unique_id
>   "T3@Qcn8AAAEAACAa6v8AAAAG"] [Mon Dec
>   13 18:09:28 2010] [error] [client
>   6**.5**.3**.1**] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator EQ match: 0. [id "960903"]
>   [msg "ModSecurity does not support
>   content encodings"] [severity
>   "WARNING"] [hostname
>   "webmail.domain****.com"] [uri
>   "/login.php"] [unique_id
>   "T3@Qcn8AAAEAACAa6v8AAAAG"] [Mon Dec
>   13 18:09:30 2010] [error] [client
>   6**.5**.3**.1**] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator EQ match: 0. [id "960903"]
>   [msg "ModSecurity does not support
>   content encodings"] [severity
>   "WARNING"] [hostname
>   "webmail.domain******.com"] [uri
>   "/imp/login.php"] [unique_id
>   "T5LVI38AAAEAACAb7LUAAAAH"]

All help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already checked for bugs/updates for all the packaged software you're running...

If you've not already done so, configure your server to save core files and get a stack trace from a crash using gdb, e.g. 'gdb /usr/sbin/httpd core' then enter bt at the prompt.

Its probably a very specific request which is causing the error - IIRC, both the access and error log are written after processing completes - IIRC mod_security can log requests when they arrive (including post vars) - switching this on would be a good idea until you know what causes the crash.